# Oracle How to list last days of months between 2 dates

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, recursive-query, date-arithmetic

I manage to get all the days between 2 dates.
But I would like to get all the lasts day of months between 2 dates (using one request).

All days between 2 dates:

```
 select to_date('01/01/2000','dd/mm/yyyy') + (LEVEL-1) as jour
 from dual
 connect by level <= to_date('31/12/2050','dd/mm/yyyy')-to_date('01/01/2000','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Last day of current month:

```
 select  LAST_DAY(sysdate)  FROM dual
```

I don't know how to mix both and get the expected result:

```
20000131
20000228
20000331
etc...
```

Comment: Are you looking to find all the month ends between two GIVEN dates, such as from 1 January 2000 to 31 December 2050? Or do you need to do this for two "input" dates, that are selected by a user when they run the query?

Answer (score 2):

That would be `DISTINCT` + `LAST_DAY`, I presume.

Setting date format (so that it matches yours; alternatively, apply `TO_CHAR` to the `jour` value with appropriate format mask):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'yyyymmdd';

Session altered.
```

I *shortened* time span to 2 years (to save space :)).

```
SQL> select distinct last_day(to_date('01/01/2000','dd/mm/yyyy') + (LEVEL-1)) as jour
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= to_date('31/12/2002','dd/mm/yyyy')-to_date('01/01/2000','dd/mm/yyyy')
  4  order by 1;

JOUR
--------
20000131
20000229
20000331
20000430
20000531
20000630
20000731
20000831
<snip>
20020630
20020731
20020831
20020930
20021031
20021130
20021231

36 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: simple solution, perfect!

Comment: This seems very inefficient - perhaps not an issue if we only need to do this for one range, but certainly important if the OP has a table with start_date and end_date columns and hundreds of thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use standard recursive queries rather than Oracle's specific `CONNECT BY` syntax. Here, you could enumerate the start of months, then offset to the end of months:

```
with cte (dt) as (
    select date '2020-01-01' dt from dual
    union all
    select dt + interval '1' month from cte where dt + interval '1' month < date '2051-01-01'
)
select last_day(dt) dt from cte order by dt
```

Note that this uses standard date literals (`date 'YYYY-MM-DD'`) rather than `to_date()` - this makes the query shorter, and, again, more standard.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7963b62a3a24c724fe19449462a31c70)**:

```
| DT        |
| :-------- |
| 31-JAN-20 |
| 29-FEB-20 |
| 31-MAR-20 |
| 30-APR-20 |
| 31-MAY-20 |
...
| 31-OCT-50 |
| 30-NOV-50 |
| 31-DEC-50 |
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the OP's stated problem. The problem was to find all ends of month(s) BETWEEN TWO DATES, such as 2020-01-15 and 2020-08-11. In such a problem, the first date can't be hard-coded. And, if the dates are 2020-01-15 to 2020-01-30, the output should be no rows.

Comment: @mathguy: that's an interpretation of the question. The original post itself does not give that level of detail on the requirement though... I took a shorter route (quite similar to Littlefoot's, actually).

Comment: Fair enough - I asked the OP for clarification, in a comment below his answer. Let's see what he says (if anything).

Comment: This fails when the input date is `2020-01-31` (or any date when there exists a later month that does not contain that day of the month). [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b252ce1b316ab1ffb1aae2ce35f56a0)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a CONNECT BY query. (You can also do it with a recursive query, like GMB has proposed, but it would have to be adapted to solve the problem you posed - it should allow for input start and end date, and it should return zero rows if there are no ends of month between the two dates.)

In the query below I use a WITH clause to give the start and end date. More likely, in your problem they are bind variables. (Or are they read from a table?)

Pay attention to the START WITH clause. The CONNECT BY condition is applied only to levels 2 and above; you need the START WITH condition for level=1, for the case when there are NO ends of month between the give dates (such as, between 10 January and 23 January of the same year).

```
with
  input_dates(start_dt, end_dt) as (
    select date '2020-01-22', date '2020-04-03' from dual
  )
select  add_months(last_day(start_dt), level - 1) as eom
from    input_dates
start   with last_day(start_dt) <= end_dt
connect by add_months(last_day(start_dt), level - 1) <= end_dt
;

EOM       
----------
2020-01-31
2020-02-29
2020-03-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial query just needs some adjustment. Instead of just level-1 (which winds up do daily) convert it to a monthly increment "level-1) * interval '1' month. Then for the connect by just get month_between the desired date.  Note: I have converted to ISO standard format for dates instead of to_date function. Makes query shorter and easier to read.

```
 select last_day(date '2000-01-01' + (level-1)*interval '1' month) as jour
   from dual
  connect by level <= 1+months_between(date '2050-12-31',date '2000-01-01');
```

Comment: This fails when the input date is `2020-01-31` (or any date when there exists a later month that does not contain that day of the month). [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aece81f76c38e54d32d234a0b1daeeff)

Comment: Interesting! Worked well here [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d09bc32821106f1bd354cbeab3ddb34c). So what is different?

Comment: February does not have 31 days, if the input date is `2020-01-31` and you add `INTERVAL '1' MONTH` then Oracle will try (and fail) to create the date `2020-02-31` for the next iteration of the hierarchical query. Never use intervals to add months.

Comment: You are correct. Guess I just have not run across it, thanks for pointing it out. BTW this seems to be a bug with Oracle interval handling. Also occurs with timestamps.  So for completeness [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f06f60b2da4e82dee206c36bd4c16f31). Fortunately being recently retired I do not actually have to worry about it anymore. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive sub-query.

This will work for:

- Multiple input ranges;
- Inputs when the start date is at the end of the month;
- When the range does not contain the end of any month.

```sql
WITH input_ranges ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  -- Should return a single row.
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-31', DATE '2020-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  -- Should return multiple rows.
  SELECT DATE '2021-02-01', DATE '2021-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  -- Should not return any rows as there is no end of the month in the range.
  SELECT DATE '2021-10-06', DATE '2021-10-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  -- Should work even though February does not have 30 days.  
  SELECT DATE '2022-01-30', DATE '2022-03-02' FROM DUAL
),
month_ends ( month_end, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT LAST_DAY( start_date ),
         end_date
  FROM   input_ranges
  WHERE  LAST_DAY( start_date ) <= end_date
UNION ALL
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS( month_end, 1 ),
         end_date
  FROM   month_ends
  WHERE  ADD_MONTHS( month_end, 1 ) <= end_date
)
SELECT month_end
FROM   month_ends
ORDER BY month_end;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | MONTH_END           |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2020-01-31 00:00:00 |
> | 2021-02-28 00:00:00 |
> | 2021-03-31 00:00:00 |
> | 2021-04-30 00:00:00 |
> | 2021-05-31 00:00:00 |
> | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 |
> | 2022-02-28 00:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f1755838375b169c5a0f7887e5cf8f25)*